# Sequential Looping through a Python Dictionary giving problems

Tags: python, associative-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In what order does python display dictionary keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458169/in-what-order-does-python-display-dictionary-keys)

There was this very weird Python question which I was trying to answer (on SO but looks like the author deleted it). This has gotten me head-over-heels and I cannot seem to plausibly explain myself what could be the cause behind this flummoxing phenomenon.
I have a Python dictionary (associative array) which I initialize as below.

```
d = {"word1": 1, "word2": 2, "word3": 3}
```

And loop through it using a for..in construct in which i print the keys  of "d" separated by a space.
**Expected output**: word1 word2 word3 
**Actual output**: word1 word3 word2

I then tried to print "d" as

```
 print d
```

Output

```
{'word1': 1, 'word3': 3, 'word2': 2}
```

I was scanning the online Python docs, existing questionnaire on SO, blogs but fully failed to figure out the cause. Am I missing something here? Furthermore, there's a kind request to all those who down-vote this question to please elaborate on the reason for the same.

Cheers. :-)

Comment: -1.  Elaboration: You dance around the subject, but you never say what it is that's wrong with the expected output vs the actual output.  The problem is in the *order*.  Google or search in stackoverflow "python", "order", "dictionary" and the answer is found pretty quickly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as an exact duplicate. Utmost thanks to all who cared to post/comment here. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation:

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary). A pair of braces creates an empty dictionary: {}. Placing a comma-separated list of key:value pairs within the braces adds initial key:value pairs to the dictionary; this is also the way dictionaries are written on output.
>
> The main operations on a dictionary are storing a value with some key and extracting the value given the key. It is also possible to delete a key:value pair with del. If you store using a key that is already in use, the old value associated with that key is forgotten. It is an error to extract a value using a non-existent key.
>
> The keys() method of a dictionary object returns a list of all the keys used in the dictionary, in arbitrary order (if you want it sorted, just apply the sorted() function to it). To check whether a single key is in the dictionary, use the in keyword.

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

The last paragraph says it all.

Answer (score 5):

Python `dict` does not guarantee any particular ordering of its keys.

[`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) preserves the insertion order of its keys.

Answer (score 4):

The keys in a Python dictionary are not sorted.

```
for key in sorted(d):
    print key,
```

prints `word1 word2 word3` as expected.