# I'm trying to convert a list of lists into a dictionary of dictionaries. It works, but not perfectly

Tags: python, dictionary

Here's the list I'm trying to convert (arbitrary numbers):

```
[['2 4', '18', '4', '32', '2'], ['2 4', '13', '9', '12', '4'], ['3 7', '435', '2
3', '123', '4', '3', '234', '34']]
```

And here is the dictionary it returns (close, but not quite). Notice how the values are out of order. I need them to be in the same order as the list:

```
{0: {'2': 0, '18': 0, '32': 0, '2 4': 0, '4': 0}, 1: {'9': 0, '13': 0, '12': 0,
'2 4': 0, '4': 0}, 2: {'23': 0, '34': 0, '3': 0, '123': 0, '4': 0, '234': 0, '43
5': 0, '3 7': 0}}
```

And finally, here is the code I'm using to convert it:

```
iterator = 0 
myDict = {} 

for listItem in myList: 
    for item in listItem[1:]: 
        myDict[iterator] = dict.fromkeys(listItem, 0) 
iterator +=1
```

edit: I forgot to mention that I'm trying to cut the first item in each list out of its corresponding dictionary.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: It can be done by `itertools`

Comment: Why do you want dicts, and why do you want order? In particular, what operations does your data structure need to support?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458169/in-what-order-does-python-display-dictionary-keys) out.

Answer (score 5):

In python, dicts are inherently unordered. This is for the reason that they are typically implemented via [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), which are more efficient than a simple associative array. Instead, you should use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), which acts just like a dict, but also remembers order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

iterator = 0 
myDict = OrderedDict()

for listItem in myList:
    myDict[iterator] = OrderedDict.fromkeys(listItem[1:], 0)
    iterator += 1
```

Note:
There's no reason to use an inner `for` loop here as well as `fromkeys`; you were just adding the entire `listItem` list in the first place since you weren't using `item` at all. If you wanted to use `item` you would have had to do this, without `fromkeys`, just using ordinary assignment:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

iterator = 0 
myDict = OrderedDict()

for listItem in myList:
    myDict[iterator] = OrderedDict()
    for item in listItem[1:]
        myDict[iterator][item] = 0
    iterator += 1
```

As a final note, python gives you nice tools so that you can write the whole thing as a one-liner using a generator expression and `enumerate`:

```
myDict = OrderedDict((i, OrderedDict.fromkeys(listItem[1:], 0))
                     for i, listItem in enumerate(myList))
```

Comment: Yeah it's how you have it in my code, I just didn't notice that when I posted. Thanks!

Comment: @Drac I edited my answer since your whole inner `for` loop was a little misguided. See the updated answer for details.