# Keeping url parameters in order when encoding with urllib

Tags: python, dictionary, get, urllib

I am trying to simulate a get request with python. I have a dictionary of parameters and am using urllib.urlencode to urlencode them

I notice that although the dictionary is of the form:

```
{ "k1":"v1", "k2":"v2", "k3":"v3", .. }
```

upon urlencoding the order of the parameters is switched to:

```
/?k1=v1&k3=v3%k2=v2...
```

why does this happen and can I force the order in the dictionary to stay the same?

Comment: All are passed as `GET` parameters, and order does not matter until `key` and its `value` gets interchanged.

Comment: this behavior comes from the fact that dictionary is a hash table. then keys are not ordered. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458169/in-what-order-does-python-display-dictionary-keys

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can see in the comments, Python dictionaries are not ordered, but there is an `OrderedDict` in Python that you can use to achieve the result you want:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import urllib
urllib.urlencode(OrderedDict([('k1', 'v1'), ('k2', 'v2'), ('k3', 'v3')]))
# Out: 'k1=v1&k2=v2&k3=v3'
```

More info about [OrderedDIct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)