# fetching mysql data as python dictionary

Tags: python, mysql

I have the below mysql table. I need to pull out the first two rows as a dictionary using python. I am using python 2.7.

```
 C1    C2    C3    C4    C5    C6    C7 

 25    33    76    87    56    76    47
 67    94    90    56    77    32    84
 53    66    24    93    33    88    99
 73    34    52    85    67    82    77
```

I use the following code

```
exp = MySQLdb.connect(host,port,user,passwd,db)
exp_cur = van.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
exp_cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table;")
data = exp_cur.fetchone() 
data_keys = data.keys() 
#print data_keys
```

The expected output (data_keys) is

```
['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7']
```

But I get

```
['C1', 'C3', 'C2', 'C5', 'C4', 'C7', 'C6']
```

What is the mistake in my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Python: use mysqldb to import a MySQL table as a dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180226/python-use-mysqldb-to-import-a-mysql-table-as-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`dict` keys have no easily predictable order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4458169/190597). To obtain the database table fields in the order in which they appear in the database, use the cursor's [description attribute](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#description):

```
fields = [item[0] for item in cursor.description]
```

---

For example,

```
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors as cursors
import config

connection = MySQLdb.connect(
    host=config.HOST, user=config.USER,
    passwd=config.PASS, db=config.MYDB,
    cursorclass=cursors.DictCursor)

with connection as cursor:
    cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test')
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE test (foo int, bar int, baz int)""")
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO test (foo, bar, baz) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""", (1,2,3))
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM test')
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    fields = [item[0] for item in cursor.description]
```

`data.keys()` may return the fields in any order:

```
    print(data.keys())
    # ['baz', 'foo', 'bar']
```

But `fields` is always `('foo', 'bar', 'baz')`:

```
    print(fields)
    # ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
data_keys = data.keys()
```

Try:

```
data_keys = exp_cur.column_names
```

Source:  [10.5.11 Property MySQLCursor.column_names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-column-names.html)

Answer (score 1):

While creating the cursor pass an argument as `dictionary=True`.

example:

```
exp = MySQLdb.connect(host,port,user,passwd,db)
exp_cur = van.cursor(dictionary=True)
```

Now when you will fetch the data, you will get a dictionary as a result.